# Index was outside the bounds of the array C# (Catch and Con(c)(q)ure)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an error, some of the users have reported recently, but i couldn't catch.[image: bound error details]

According to research i think it can be solved with changing Dictionary to ConcurrentDictionary. The question is how can i catch the error? What is the best way to use ConcurrentDictionary for adding (TryAdd or AddorUpdate)?

Edit: codes in references.

```
    private static Dictionary<string, SportsFacility> _selectedFacilities = new Dictionary<string, SportsFacility>();
    public static SportsFacility SelectedFacility
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedFacilities.ContainsKey(HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID) ? _selectedFacilities[HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID] : null;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedFacilities.ContainsKey(HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID))
            {
                _selectedFacilities[HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID] = value;
            }
            else
            {
                _selectedFacilities.Add(HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code which generated the error?

Comment: Please take a moment to read this- [MCVE] and format your question accordingly

Comment: New around here. Thank you for hint.

Comment: Do you know that IIS can decide to recycle your AppPool and everything on _selectedFacilities will be erased? Why don't you use the Session?

Comment: *Why* are you trying to create your own session cache? ASP.NET provides its own mechanisms to keep state for a single sessions (Session) or cache data for all sessions (Cache) that work correctly across a farm. What you try here won't work if you use 2 or more machines for load balancing or if IIS recycles the apppool. You can configure both to use memory, a database, Redis etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never minding the reason for working with the session id like this (there are certainly better ways of doing this), here is a slight improvement to your code:

```
private static readonly object _selectedFacilitiesLocker=new object();
private static Dictionary<string, SportsFacility> _selectedFacilities = new Dictionary<string, SportsFacility>();

private static bool TryGetSelectedFacility(string key, out SportsFacility facility)
{
    // Since you are in a web environment and are using statics, you must lock this index whenever you use it
    lock(_selectedFacilitiesLocker)
    {
        return _selectedFacilities.TryGetValue(key, out facility);
    }
}
private static void UpdateSelectedFacility(string key, SportsFacility facility)
{
    // Since you are in a web environment and are using statics, you must lock this index whenever you use it
    lock(_selectedFacilitiesLocker)
    {
        _selectedFacilities[key] = facility;
    }
}
public static SportsFacility SelectedFacility
{
    get
    {
        SportsFacility facility;
        if(!TryGetSelectedFacility(HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID, out facility))
            return null;
        else 
            return facility;
    }
    set
    {
        UpdateSelectedFacility(HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID, value);
    }
}
```

Using a static index ("_selectedFacilities") like you do in your code spells trouble in a multi threaded environment, like a web server. If you want a design like this (without going into the reasons for why you shouldn't), you must add a lock around it whenever you use it. Otherwise you'll get all kinds of strange bugs as soon as you're in production. It may seem to work while you're happily testing yourself but life isn't that easy, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

This exception caused by using dictionary object from multiple threads without syncronizing. You can solve it by syncronizing access to dictionary object with lock (as @KEkegren suggested) or with [ReaderWriterLockSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx)

In addition to syncronizing manually, as you said, you can use [ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) without using locks. It is supported on .NET Framework 4 and above.

All operations on ConcurrentDictionary are atomic, meaning all methods are thread safe and you do not need to syncronize access.

However you should not use the same way as Dictionary. I mean, you should not check for key existence and after that add a new value. Instead you should use AddOrUpdate in your case because it makes what you are trying to do in a single atomic operation.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than criticizing a particular approach, provide an answer that shows a better solution.

This does the same thing you are doing with a static dictionary using session variables.

```
public static SportsFacility SelectedFacility
{
    get
    {
        return (Session["SelectedFacility"] as SportsFacility);
    }
    set
    {
        Session["SelectedFacility"] = value;
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: It may not be the same thing, with a shared dictionary one can access and enumerate all sessions data. It is not clear in question what is the purpose of this Dictionary and OP did not answer a comment for using session state.

Comment: You're certainly right. He may be enumerating the collection as well. We can only work with the code He's given us.